# Javascript only works on first Contact 7 Form on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I have two contact 7 forms on my page (section 3 and 10), only the top one will follow the javascript function. If I add another form to the top of the page, the new top one works and the other one stops working. It doesn't seem to matter if I make a new function for each form or not.
Page is http://www.sportshosts.com/new-home/

If it works, the pop up on the following page will have registered your details - it currently only does it for the first. Don't forget to clear in Javascript console before testing next one with `localStorage.clear();`

I have this in the additional settings of the top form:`on_sent_ok: "js_viralloopsinfo();"`
and this in the second: `on_sent_ok: "js_bottomviralloopform();"`

This is the javascript

```
function js_viralloopsinfo() {
  VL.extraData = {}
  VL.options.form_fields.form_firstName = jQuery("#firstname").val();
  VL.options.form_fields.form_email = jQuery("#email").val(); 
  VL.createLead(function() {
    //any logic to run after the participation
  });
} 
function js_bottomviralloopform() {
  VL.extraData = {}
  VL.options.form_fields.form_firstName = jQuery("#firstname").val();
  VL.options.form_fields.form_email = jQuery("#email").val(); 
  VL.createLead(function() {
    //any logic to run after the participation
  });
}
```

Even if I add a form that works on another page to the top, the new top one will work and the previous top one no longer works.

Comment: Not clear with issue.only one contact form is there

Comment: There's two forms - they're both sign up forms, one on the white and grey background on section 3 and one in the orange section 10. You'll notice the pop up on the page after submission won't register your details for the second form, but will for the first.

Comment: You can't have duplicated id's on page, fix that and then try again...

Comment: I see that you use same ID for both functions, maybe you have non-unique ID's in page?

Comment: It worked. Thanks!